# Maximal permutation groups where $1$ is fixed iff $2$ is fixed

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, permutations, combinatorial-group-theory

Let $S_n$ denote the symmetric group on $\lbrace 1,2,\ldots ,n\rbrace$, for $n\geq 2$, and let

$$
\begin{align}
X&= \lbrace \sigma \in S_n \mid \sigma(1)=1 \Leftrightarrow \sigma(2)=2\rbrace \\
&=
\lbrace \sigma \in S_n \mid\sigma(1)=1, \sigma(2)=2\rbrace \cup 
\lbrace \sigma \in S_n \ | \ \sigma(1) \neq 1, \sigma(2) \neq 2\rbrace
\end{align}$$

Denote by $sg(X)$ the sets of all subgroups of $S_n$ contained in $X$.

**Question.** What are the maximal elements of $sg(X)$ for inclusion ?

Obviously, the stabilizer subgroup $M_1=\lbrace \sigma \in S_n \mid \sigma(\lbrace 1,2 \rbrace)= \lbrace 1,2 \rbrace \rbrace$ is one such maximal element. But (at least for large enough $n$) there are others : if $\tau$ is any product of two or more disjoint cycles of the same length, with one cycle containing $1$ and another containing $2$, then $\langle\tau\rangle \in sg(X)$, but $\tau\not\in M_1$, so any maximal element containing $\langle \tau\rangle $ will be different from $M_1$.

Comment: If $n$ is even, then you get a large family of examples in the following way: let $\mathcal{P}$ be a partition of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ into $n/2$ parts of size $2$, one part being $\{1,2\}$. The the partition preserver has shape $S_2^{n/2}\rtimes S_{n/2}$ is contained in $sg(X)$ and is maximal even in $S_n$. There are many such partitions, so many such subgroups.

Comment: If $n$ is odd, you can pass to a $S_{n-1}$ subgroup fixing a point (other than $1$ or $2$),  and then pass to maximal subgroup as the above one. I didn't check super carefully, but I think this will be maximal in $sg(X)$.

Comment: Note that your elements $\tau$ are contained in the subgroups above. (Just take the first part to be $\{1,2\}$, then the next part the image of $\{1,2\}$ under $\tau$, and so on...)

Comment: As a wild guess, I would say that "generically", these should probably be the only examples. There might be others coming from maximal primitive subgroups of $S_n$, or other weirder things happening, but that's my guess.